# How does syntax like "has_many" interact with the Class objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, syntax

My goal is to implement something like "has_many" in Rails' ActiveRecord. I want to understand more about how the classes/objects are loaded.

What is happening when I use "has_many" in the following?

```
class Widget < MiniRecord
   has_many :trinkets
end
```

Let's say that this is the implementation of "MiniRecord":

```
class MiniRecord
  class << self
    def has_many associated_model
      @associations[:has_many] << associated_model_sym 
    end
  end

  def list_associations
    do_stuff(@associations) # Where do I instantiate @associations?
  end
end
```

I've gotten it to the point where it works, but I have some messy code that I'd like to trim down.

I want to understand how this works, but **specifically, where should I instantiate @associations?**

I want to be able to "declare" attributes in subclasses of `MiniRecord` that is defined when the class is defined (i.e. a static variable), and then act on these attributes later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you extend `MiniRecord`, say `MyRecord`, you got a class hierarchy figure something like the following (`#SomeClass` is eigenclass or singleton class of `SomeClass`):

```
                             Class
                               |
MiniRecord    --class-->   #MiniRecord
   |                           |
MyRecord      --class-->   #MyRecord
```

Where the `list_associations` method is defined on `MiniRecord` and `has_many` is defined on `#MiniRecord`.

When you call `has_many` in `MyRecord`'s class body, it will first look up the method in `#MyRecord`, which will fail. Then it will look up in `#MiniRecord` and found the definition. If it fails somehow, it will look in `Class` for the definition. That's how this approach works.

For the question

> **specifically, where should I instantiate @associations?**

You have two choice:

1. initialize when used

   ```
   def has_many associated_model
     @associations ||= Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = [] }
     @associations[:has_many] << associated_model_sym 
   end
   ```
2. initialize when the descendant class get created

   ```
   class MiniRecord
     def self.inherited klass
       klass.instance_variable_set(:@associations, Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = [] }
     end
   end
   ```

Note that you cannot access `@associations` in instance method `list_associations` directly, because it's in different scope. You need to expose `@associations` on `MiniRecord` and then get the value from there.

```
class MiniRecord
  class << self
    def has_many associated_model
      @associations[:has_many] << associated_model
    end

    attr_reader :associations
  end

  def self.inherited klass
    klass.instance_variable_set(:@associations, Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = [] })
  end

  def list_associations
    do_stuff(self.class.associations) # Where do I instantiate @associations?
  end

  def do_stuff sth
    p sth
  end
end

class MyRecord < MiniRecord
  has_many :thrinks
end

r = MyRecord.new
r.list_associations
p MyRecord.associations
```